# Integer Power C++ Function with base and exponent parameters

Tags: c++

I would like to know if this is a good solution for a function that has to computer the power of integers given base and exponent.
The solution must include solution for negative numbers.
I'm trying to learn C++ trough a Deitel book and I'm doing several exercises.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double integerPower(int base, int exponent){
    double result = 1;
    if(exponent >=0){
    for (int i = 0; i < exponent; i ++){
        result *= base;
        }
    } else {
        exponent *= -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < exponent; i ++){
                result /= base;
                }
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    int base, exponent;
    double result;
    cout << "Insert the base: " << endl;
    cin >> base;
    cout << "Insert the exponent: " << endl;
    cin >> exponent;
    result = integerPower(base, exponent);
    cout <<"The result is: " << result << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Use the standard library

If you are going to give the result as a `double`, then this function isn't really a pure integer power calculator. And in that case, just use [`std::pow()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow). It has overloads for integer exponents that the compiler can optimize for.

## A pure integer power function

If you just want to work purely on integers, then the typical algorithm to calculate a number raised to an arbitrary power efficiently is by recognizing that, for example, \$x^4 = ((x * x) * (x * x))\$, and so you can calculate \$y = x * x\$, and then \$x^4 = y * y\$. This only needs two multiplications instead of 3. So basically, you can divide and conquer the problem:

```
int integerPower(int base, int exponent) {
    if (exponent == 0)
        return 1;

    int result = integerPower(base, exponent / 2);
    int result *= result;

    if (exponent & 1)
            result *= base;

    return result;
}
```

The above doesn't work for negative exponents, but then again that is not very useful if the result is just an integer.

Comment: _If the base and the exponent are both negative, then mathematically the result will be a complex number_ - not so. You confuse it with negative base and _fractional_ exponent. A negative exponent is just a division.

Comment: @vnp Oops! I should've known that. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @G.Sliepen If the power is negative, call the function again with the positive of the power, and the reciprocal of the base. For example, if the function is called with 10 as base and -5 as power. Call the function again with 5 as power, and 1/10 as the base (reciprocal). This way you can calculate it for negative exponents too.

Comment: x ^ -y = (1/x) ^ y